# Jenkins error - NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method, what is wrong with my groovy code

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I want to write a Groovy method for a jenkins pipeline to check a connection of defined servers. I get the NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$'... and I have no idea what this error has to do with the code for this jenkins pipeline. I'm new in groovy and pipeline syntax.

This is my jenkins pipeline with the groovy method 'reachable':

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Init') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def minutes = params.minutes.toInteger()
                    def remotehost = params.remotehost.toString()
                    def nr = 1
                    for (int i = 0; i < minutes; i++) {
                        stage("Stage ${nr}") {
                            if (reachable(${remotehost}) == true) {
                                break
                            } else {
                                echo "Running stage ${nr}"
                                nr = nr + 1
                                sleep(60)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def reachable( String host ) {

ecode = sh ( "ping -c1 ${host} >/dev/null 2>&1; echo \$?", returnStdout: true )
if (ecode.toInteger() == 0) {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}

}
```

Can any of you help me to solve the problem?

Of course, I have already asked Google for the solution.